# Problemas con la validaciones de los campos de los formularios

Tags: laravel

estoy utilizando Laravel 5.6.13 e Infiom para generar los CRUDs pero tengo un problema a la hora de las validaciones que se hacen en el mismo formulario, como que el correo no se pueda entrar repetido o djar campos vacios, etc. les pongo un ejemplo de la parte de gestion de usuarios. estos son los campos

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Email Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

y esta es la vista

```
<div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'users.store']) !!}

                    @include('users.fields')

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

como hago para que me mustre lso errores en los campos.

Comment: Si imprime la variable $errors , obtiene los errores? si muestra los errores entonces están funcionando bien sus validaciones , ahora para mostrar estos errores ¿Boots3 o Boots4?

Comment: Estoy usando Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi utilizando el formato que implementa laravel por defecto no es precisamente lo que queria pero funciona

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 has-feedback{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('email', 'Correo:') !!}
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
    <span class=" form-control-feedback"></span>

    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
    @endif
</div>
```